# How to horizontally center align this absolutely positioned `<a>` tag inside the relatively positioned div?

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-align

In the following SSCCE, I want the 5th `<a>` element to horizontally align in the center.

I have tried `align="center"` HTML attribute, as well as `text-align:center` CSS property on `.wrapper` div but nothing seems to work.

So how can I get this to work? **What should I do to horizontally align the 5th '' element?**

**Note:** *The given code is an example. In the real web page, I can have a total of 6  tags, in which case I will like to horizontally center align the 2 's in the 2nd row; and I can have 7  elements in which case I will have to center align the 3 's in the 2nd row...so on.* The maximum number of  tags  in any row, as it must be apparent, is 4.

[image]

***SSCCE - index.php***

```
<?php 

$number_of_anchors=5;
$images_array = array('http://shutupandtakemethere.com/pics/022014/stairs-in-a-japanese-garden-big.jpg', 'http://piximus.net/media/9366/beautiful-places-on-the-world-20.jpg', 'http://freetopwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/free-beautiful-place-wallpaper-hd-161.jpg', 'http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/6900000/Beautiful-Places-national-geographic-6969096-1600-1200.jpg', 'http://www.advertising-photographer-new-york.com/galleries/Travel%20Photographs/photos/spain_countryside_3984.jpg', 'http://www.brisbane-australia.com/media/images/2011_somerset_dam_countryside.jpg', 'http://www.worldholidaydestinations.com/australia/nsw/glen-innes/row3-photo1.jpg', 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/original/21768043.jpg', 'http://www.countrysideshow.co.uk/sites/default/files/imagecache/HP_SS1_990x514/rotor/hh%20ss%201.jpg');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>


<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

    <?php
    $anchor_width=0;

    if ($number_of_anchors<4) {
        $anchor_width=(100/3);
    } else if ($number_of_anchors>=4) {
        $anchor_width=(100/4);
    }

    $anchor_left=0;

    $anchor_top=0;


    for ($j=1; $j<=$number_of_anchors; $j++) {
        //echo 'The value of $j is '.$j.'<br>';//check

        //echo '$j: '.$j.'<br>';
        //echo '$j%4 : '.($j%4).'<br>';
        if ($j%4==1) {
            //echo 'Entered the ($j%4==1) condition.';
            if ($j!=1) {
                //echo ' Also entered the ($j!=1) condition.';
                $anchor_top = $anchor_top + 300 + 20;//because the height of an anchor is 300 and 20 is the top and bottom padding of 10.
                $anchor_left = 0;
            }
        }

        echo '<a class="anchor anchor'.($j).'" href="#" style="top:'.$anchor_top.'px; left:'.$anchor_left.'%; width:'.($anchor_width-1).'%; background-image: url('.$images_array[$j-1].');">';
            echo '<!--<span class="span-container">
                        <span class="span-one">SPAN ONE</span>
                        <span class="span-two">SPAN TWO</span>
            </span>-->';
        echo '</a>';

        $anchor_left = $anchor_left + $anchor_width;


    }

    ?>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

***styles.css***

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    max-width:90%;
    margin: 0px auto;

    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}


.anchor1 {
    left:0px;
}

.anchor2 {
    left:25%;
}

.anchor3 {
    left:50%;
}

.wrapper .anchor::before {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    content: " ";
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.anchor {
    position: absolute;
    /*height: 25vw;*/
    height:300px;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 190px;
    top: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.span-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

.span-one {
    font-size: 271.579%;
    color: #FFF;
}

.span-two {
    font-size: 214.737%;
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **achieve** what you want:

You need to **change** a couple of **styles** in your **css**.

**First:** Add `text-align: center;` to your `wrapper` class.

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    max-width:90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Second:** Change `position: absolute;` to `display: inline-block;` then add `width: 24%;` in your `anchor` class.

```
.anchor {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    height:300px;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 190px;
    top: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

**Note:** You can remove now the other `.anchorX` in your css. E.g. `.anchor1`, `.anchor2` and `.anchor3`.

**Third:** Remove the unnecessary `properties` of `span-container` and `span-two` class. It will look like this:

```
.span-container {
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}

.span-one {
    font-size: 271.579%;
    color: #FFF;
}

.span-two {
    font-size: 214.737%;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 0.9;
}
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/b7d8nw0a/1/).**

**Reminder:** If your going to use `max-width` property, set the `width` property not exceeding the `max-width` value.

**Update:**

To align the `span-container` class to the **bottom** of the `anchor` class. Add `position: relative;` in the `anchor` class then add `position: absolute;` in the `span-container` class.

**Updated [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/b7d8nw0a/5/).**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey that has disrupted the alignment of the `.span-container`. It was aligned to the bottom-left by `bottom:10%; left:10%;`. Now that doesn't seem to work and it seems to be aligned to the top.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you can suggest something for that.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, I had rather upvoted it. I had also accepted your answer but removed it just to open the question again. Once the issue gets solved, I'll accept it again. =)

Answer (score 0):

Have the link inside of a p element, like this:

```html
<div>
  <p align="center">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">centered link to google inside a div tag</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You know, I don't get why this isn't as easy as just give the a element the align attribute...

Comment: You know, I wrote a small SSCCE (which is a complete example project) in the question so that you can copy the code on your machine and run it, in case you wonder something like that. I have already mentioned in the question that `align` or `text-align` did not work. `margin:0 auto` also did not work.